# apple push notification servicce ssl certificate expired?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, auto-update

I was registered for apns service few days back.

Now iam in confusion if my ssl certificate expires?

so i googled it and found a solution every time  supposed to create a new certificate 
and upload it on my server. i think it is a long process and it needs maintainence on server side.
Is there any way do it from client side automatically so that every year we don't want to update in server.
any suggestions would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it is. Apple issues a one year push certificate, and once it expires, you have to create a new one.

The generation of the new certificate is a manual process (involving the Keychain Access app and the iOS provisioning portal).

Finally you must upload the new certificate to your server (since your server needs that certificate to send push notifications), so you have to update the server. There is no way to around that.

Is updating the server once a year such a trouble?

Comment: thanks for reply.just for conformation i asked this one, any way thanks

Comment: means i supposed to delete the old one and create a new one or is  there any renew option

Comment: @siva Yes, you have to create a new one. As far as I know there is no renewal option.

Comment: @Eran is there any need to rebuild the application and upload it?

Comment: @Johnykutty I'm almost certain you don't need to rebuild the application (assuming that you are not sending push notifications from your app).